# How to send emails from jBoss when an error/exception occurs?

Tags: email, jboss, error-handling

I would like to set my jBoss (4.2.3GA) server so it could send an email to an exchange mailbox everytime an exception occurs, so developers and administrators would be able to see what's going on using their mobile phones.

Any thoughts?

Thank you very much

Charles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a log4j appender

```
log4j.appender.sendMail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.sendMail.To=<email id>
log4j.appender.sendMail.From=</email><email id>
log4j.appender.sendMail.SMTPHost=<mail hostname>
log4j.appender.sendMail.Subject=Log4J Message
log4j.appender.sendMail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

[log4j doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

Comment: It's important to note that SMTPAppender should be ASYNC, otherwise you can run into dead locks when the SMTP server goes down.